# Ruby date parse inconsistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, date, utc

I can't understand why Date.utc is making this difference:

Please not that the date is different:

```
1.9.3-p327 :009 > time = Date.parse("2013-07-04 15:39:45 -0700").to_time
 => 2013-07-04 00:00:00 +0300
```

and:

```
1.9.3-p327 :010 > time = Date.parse("2013-07-04 15:39:45 -0700").to_time.utc
 => 2013-07-03 21:00:00 UTC
```

UPDATE:
Even if I provide the UTC within the date string, still 4th of July becomes 3rd.

```
1.9.3-p327 :017 > time = Date.parse("2013-07-04 1:00:00 UTC").to_time.utc
 => 2013-07-03 21:00:00 UTC 
1.9.3-p327 :018 > time = Date.parse("2013-07-04 21:00:00 UTC").to_time.utc
 => 2013-07-03 21:00:00 UTC 
1.9.3-p327 :019 > time = Date.parse("2013-07-04 23:00:00 UTC").to_time.utc
 => 2013-07-03 21:00:00 UTC
```

My guess is this is because Date.parse doesn't accept an indication about UTC as a parameter. How would you make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try `DateTime.parse("2013-07-04 1:00:00 UTC").to_time`

Comment: DateTime.parse("2013-07-04 1:00:00 UTC").to_time
 => 2013-07-04 04:00:00 +0300

Comment: Please see my comments `DateTime.parse("2013-07-04 1:00:00 UTC").to_time.utc`

Comment: That's the answer, please add it :) So is Date is parsing dates, and DateTime includes also the time. This explains. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try `DateTime.parse("2013-07-04 1:00:00 UTC").to_time.utc`

I got

`irb(main):003:0>require 'date'

irb(main):005:0> DateTime.parse("2013-07-04 1:00:00 UTC").to_time.utc

=> 2013-07-04 01:00:00 UTC`

Thanks